# JSON parsing and aura iteration in salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helper, aura-iteration

Below is the link of format

[JSON example](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=645a2373d26a892d3b47057a719fd004)

I am trying to bind the data which is there in results-> items using aura:iteration. Here is my code for that.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.newassets.result.item}" var="item" start="1">
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!item.id!=null}">
        <li class="slds-truncate slds-list__item">{!item.id} : {!item.name}</li>
    </aura:renderIf>
</aura:iteration>

var action = component.get("c.XXXXXXXXXXXX");
action.setParams({
    "userid": '###'
});
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") 
    {
        var data = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.newassets");
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

I am using aura enabled methods to get the data whose return type is `JSONParser`.

My api calls and response is coming right. I have checked that using the debug logs and I can see the data coming.

When I change the datatype from `JSONParser` to `String` and debug the helper js I can see the data in string format which I don't want. It was just to check whether the data in coming back from the Apex class.

But when the return type is `JSONParser` the data is not binding. I know I am not doing something right.

Comment: ¿the attribure newassets is a Object or a String?

Comment: It is an Object `<aura:attribute name="newassets" type="Object"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Apex class returns the Object in String format, then You Just do `JSON.parse("Your_return_String")` to get as an Object.

EDIT:
You have not set Attribute value to 'newassets'.<s>`component.set('v.newassets')`</s>

Example code working fine to me.

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="obj" type="Map"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.obj.result.item}" var="item" start="1">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!item.id!=null}">
            <li class="slds-truncate slds-list__item">{!item.id} : {!item.name}</li>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:iteration> 
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init: function(component){
        var obj = {
            "status": 0,
            "result": {
                "new": 7,
                "item": [
                    {
                        "id": 21022,
                        "name": "Print1"
                    } ,
                    {
                        "id": 210223,
                        "name": "Print12"
                    } 
                ]

            }
        } 

    component.set('v.obj', obj);
    }
})
```

Check this Out.

Comment: I had set the return type to `String` just to check if my calls to apex class were working or not. And I don't to bind the html using the `jquery/javascript`. I want to use `aura:iteration`

Comment: I can't get you Clearly. What you are going to set on 'newassets' attribute and What you want to Iterate on aura:iteration ?

Comment: If you had read my question correctly you would have understood it. I want to iterate on results->item of and bind the values of it say id or name. Just look at the JSON example link I had attaced with the question.

Comment: I have Edited the Answer. Take a look.